# Ignite - Create a Cache through console.gridgain.com but it does not show in console's queries pag

Tags: web, console, ignite, gridgain

I create a Cache through console.gridgain.com, but it does not show in console queries page.

Does anybody meet this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you did not configure SQL table for this cache. Not all caches in GridGain have corresponding tables.